# Reduce code and database redundancy between multiple Django projects

Tags: django, project, redundancy

I have multiple Django projects that have commonalities in their code and databases, how can I merge the commonalities into a core project to reduce redundancy?

The best solution I can think of is to make each project to communicate with the core one through http, but this would decrease the efficiency. I also need to store users into the core project so using http would even be less safe.

I also read about Django Rest Framework, maybe I should use it as part of the solution.

Comment: You wanna expand on the "commonalities" you speak of here? What are they exactly?

Comment: Basically views that create/get/change certain model instances depending on the request, and the models those models themselves.

E.g. project A and project B both require the clients to register a user but I want the code that handles the registration and the user instances to be in the core project (D).

Comment: I suppose you can write some mixin or use the factory method design pattern to accomplish your task.